# How are pytest fixure scopes intended to work?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I want to use pytest fixtures to prepare an object I want to use across a set of tests.
I follow the [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#scope-sharing-fixtures-across-classes-modules-packages-or-session) and create a fixture in `something_fixture.py` with its scope set to **session** like this:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def something():
    return 'something'
```

Then in `test_something.py` I try to use the fixture like this:

```py
def test_something(something):
    assert something == 'something'
```

Which does not work, but if I import the fixture like this:

```
from tests.something_fixture import something


def test_something(something):
    assert something == 'something'
```

the test passes...

Is this import *necessary*? Because to me this is not clear according to the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This session-scoped fixture should be defined in a `conftest.py` module, see [*`conftest.py`: sharing fixtures across multiple files*](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/fixtures.html#conftest-py-sharing-fixtures-across-multiple-files) in the docs.

> The `conftest.py` file serves as a means of providing fixtures for an entire directory. Fixtures defined in a `conftest.py` can be used by any test in that package without needing to import them (pytest will automatically discover them).

By writing the fixture in `something_fixture.py` it was defined somewhere that went "unnoticed" because there was no reason for Python to import this module. The default test collection phase considers filenames matching [these glob patterns](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#confval-python_files):

```
- test_*.py
- *_test.py
```

Since it's a session-scoped feature, [define it instead in a `conftest.py` file](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/fixtures.html#scope-sharing-fixtures-across-classes-modules-packages-or-session), so it will be created at test collection time and available to all tests.

You can remove the import statement `from tests.something_fixture import something`. In fact the "tests" subdirectory generally doesn't need to be importable at all.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. I thought pytest collects all fixtures and provides them dynamically as needed.

Comment: It's not really safe for them to do that, because there can be random .py scripts lying around in directories and they can not just eagerly import all these (maybe some are operational scripts). So, you have to be explicit about what are the test files, or reconfigure the collection patterns if you don't like the defaults.